# Issues with websocket with ssl : connection reset

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Trying to setup a simple node server to relay informations;
I can connect using https; but when i connect thru websocket (wss://) I get a :

echo.js:136 WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx:3000/socket.io?encoding=text' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

I don't understand why; pull my hairs out here,

What obvious thing am i missing ?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem', 'utf8');
var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var http = require('https').createServer(credentials, app);
// var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function(){ console.log('listening on *:3000');});

var serverID = 'undefined';
io.on('connection', function (socket){
    console.log('a user connected: ' + socket.id + " (server: " + serverID + " )");
    
    // register the server id, received the command from unity
    socket.on('RegServerId', function (data){
        serverID = socket.id;
        console.log('reg server id : ' + serverID);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        if (serverID == socket.id)
        {
           serverID = 'undefined';
           console.log('removed Server: ' + socket.id);
        }
        else
        {
           console.log('user disconnected: ' + socket.id);
        }
    });

    socket.on('OnReceiveData', function (data){
        if (serverID != 'undefined')
        {
            switch(data.EmitType)
            {
                //emit type: all;
                case 0: io.emit('OnReceiveData', { DataString: data.DataString, DataByte: data.DataByte }); break;
                //emit type: server;
                case 1: io.to(serverID).emit('OnReceiveData', { DataString: data.DataString, DataByte: data.DataByte }); break;
                //emit type: others;
                case 2: socket.broadcast.emit('OnReceiveData', { DataString: data.DataString, DataByte: data.DataByte }); break;
            }
        }
    else
    {
        console.log('cannot find any active server');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Localhost isn't supported when using certificates I believe, you can just use ws for testing locally.

Comment: Thanks but it's not localhost; read the question carefully.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that, I'm not sure when working with socket.io that you can use websocket to connect (or maybe it needs the protocol?), mostly I create ws server myself, I'll check later today...

Comment: Any luck? Tried ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket?